# Sometimes firebase cloud functions didn't execute

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi I'm using a cloud function to aggregate data created on a sub-collection to the parent collection, when I test it it works like a charm, but when I deploy it to my production environment that sometimes (is not common but occurs) the data is no aggregated to the parent document.

I think that the function is not executed because I don't get any error on the logs.

Here is my function code

```js
exports.aggregateTranlationsToSong = functions.firestore
    .document("songs2/{songId}/translations/{langId}")
    .onCreate((event, context) => {
        const { songId, langId } = context.params;

        console.log({ songId, langId });

        let songRef = admin
            .firestore()
            .collection("songs2")
            .doc(songId);

        return admin
            .firestore()
            .runTransaction(transaction => {
                return transaction.get(songRef).then(songSnap => {
                    let actualSongData = songSnap.data();

                    let translations = actualSongData.lyric_translations;
                    if (translations === undefined || translations === null)
                        translations = {};

                    translations[langId] = true;
                    console.log({ translations });

                    return transaction.update(songRef, {
                        lyric_translations: translations
                    });
                });
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.error(e);
            });
    });
```

Comment: You mentioned that your logs do not show any error, have you checked if your `console.log()` are being called? That would confirm if the function is being triggered or not. Also, your code appears to be correct, so if the function is not being triggered, it might be a good idea for you to contact GCP Support by opening a [Issue Tracker's Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0) so that they can take a look at your project an determine what happened.

Comment: Yes I can see my `console.log()` on the function logs correctly but I think that sometimes the function didn't execute because I can see some some documents whitout the aggregated data

Comment: When I see a log and go to the referred document the data is aggregated correctly, I can't reproduce it by my self its something that happens sometimes when my users interact with the app

Comment: Being an intemitent issue, it's kind of hard to pin point what could be causing it. You would either have to get a reproducible record to troubleshoot step by step or contact support to check your project and see what could be route cause, because it does not appear to be your code causing it.